# Zapier CLI Dynamic Dropdown, how to set multiple values to bundle.inputData

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

Currently building a Zapier app but running into a blocker when trying to pass information from a dynamic dropdown.

Ideally, I want to be able to set an object of data to `bundle.inputData` whenever someone selects an item. The[docs](https://zapier.github.io/zapier-platform/#dynamic-dropdowns) only provide a single value solution, but wondering if anybody knows of a solution to this?

Example of the problem:

```
//User Data
[
  {id:1, name: Tommy, email: tom@gmail.com},
  {id:2, name: Bill, email: bill@gmail.com},
  {id:3, name: Greg, email: greg@gmail.com}
]

//Input Field as part of the operation object
inputFields: [
      {
        key: 'users',
        required: true,
        label: 'Select user to notify',
        dynamic: 'users.email.name',
      },
]
```

Instead of passing back an `email` when a user selects an item, I want to be able to send both `name` and `email` as part of the `bundle.inputData`.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Combine Name/Email as a string in trigger and separate when making final HTTP request.

Example:

```
const combineUserEmail = (name, email) => `${name}/${email}`;

const triggerUsers = async(z, bundle) =>{
  const response = await z.request({
     url: https://blahblah.com/users
  });
  const users = z.JSON parse(response.content);
  const results = users.map((user, i) =>({id: i, user: combineUserEmail(item.name, item.email)})
}
```